# Prevent parent mouseout jQuery event to trigger on child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is probably a known issue or question. However, I only see results for

```
Element.on('click', callback)
```

events and I do not know how to do this with and on 'mouseout' event

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="oneTodo">
  <div class="todoText"></div>

  <span class="eraseTodo">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-close-outline"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

And my script:

```
$('.oneTodo').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.eraseTodo').fadeIn(100);
});

$('.oneTodo').on('mouseout', function() { // this is what is not working
    $(this).find('.eraseTodo').fadeOut(100);
});
```

Basically when I hover over my:

```
<span class="eraseTodo">
  <i class="icon ion-ios-close-outline"></i>
</span>
```

since it basically is not the .oneTodo div anymore it fades Out. I want to prevent this. How can I achieve this?

P.S: I tried:

```
$('.oneTodo:not(.eraseTodo)').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).find('.eraseTodo').fadeOut(100);
});
```

but failed miserably.

Comment: Could you please make a fiddle?

Comment: i think what you are looking for is not `hover` but `mouseenter`

Comment: @Chris I tried it and I still have the same effect. I positioned the span absolute. I think that is what affecting the trigger, because it normally wouldnt be withing the div that triggers the event.

Comment: some explanations about what's happening: if you have a div inside another, when you hover the inner div, it is considered as going out from the outer div (you can hover just one element at a time). You need something like testing if you didn't entered the inner div before hiding the element

Comment: sorry, i missed `mouseleave`. `hover` is the pendant to `mouseout` and `mouseenter` is the pendant to `mouseleave`. example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbJddX

Comment: @Chris thank you so much !!!!!!